# Blender mirror problem

Tags: mirror, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to mirror an arch and then subdivide to get a smooth look but vertices that should be merged in the process do not behave as I would assume. I cannot subdivide and moreover, shading gets distorted.

Here's a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3lguvtfWr0

How can I apply this mirror modifier so it works normal?

PS:blender 2.78a

[image]

Comment: Issues are not sourced by the same but one of the answers helped me. Mesh had face where mirror modifier merged the vertices. I deleted the face and problem solved.